# In Extent report 5 screenshots getting broken in other system, working fine in my local system

Tags: selenium-webdriver, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

```
Please check and let me know anything need to modify
```

Below code written inside base page:

```
public static String getScreenshot1() throws IOException {
        String dateName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss").format(new Date());
        TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
        File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

    
        String destination = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Screenshots/" + dateName + ".png";
        File finalDestination = new File(destination);
        
        FileHandler.copy(source, finalDestination);
        return destination;
    }
```

## Below code written inside  Main class:

```
test.log(Status.PASS, "Browser must navigate to Login page",
                    MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(getScreenshot1()).build());
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the screenshots available across all the system, we can convert the screenshot as base64 string and then attach it in ExtentReport.

To convert a screenshot path to base64 image:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(getScreenshot1());
byte[] imageBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
String base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageBytes);

test.log(Status.PASS,"Attached Screenshot ", MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromBase64String("data:image/png;base64,"+base64).build());
```

You can refer the extent report documentation [here](https://www.extentreports.com/docs/versions/5/java/index.html#logging-screenshots).